# Emacs setting up ESS : cannot open load file no such file or directory, julia-mode

Tags: emacs

I am trying to setup ESS for emacs following:
http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/readme.html#Installation

But when i execute the make command in the source directory it shows error:

**cannot open load file no such file or directory, julia-mode**

The same error shows up when i start emac without compiling the source but added the folowing to my **init.el**:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/ESS/lisp/")
(load "ess-site")
```

I don't know what's the problem i don't even want to use julia i am only setting it up for **R syntax highlighting**

can anyone please help?

Comment: Use the _released version_ from [here](http://ess.r-project.org/index.php?Section=download) rather than the git version.

Comment: What version of Emacs do you have? (Check with `M-x version RET`.)

Comment: Thanks using the release version solved the isssue!